# Colorbar in legend when using plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Here is my data:

```
set.seed(42)
mydata = data.frame(A = rnorm(20), B = rnorm(20), Index = sample(190:400,20))
```

I am trying to divide the data into 20 different intervals based on the `Index` value and then color the scatter points according to their interval `value`. Below is my code. It is not working perfectly.

```
cols = colorRampPalette(c("red", "black"), space = "rgb")(20)
mydata$interval = cut(mydata$Index,breaks = 20)
mydata$cols = cols[mydata$interval]
require(plotly)
x = list(title = "A")
y = list(title = "B")
plot_ly(mydata, x = ~A, y = ~B,  color = ~cols, type = "scatter",
                        mode = 'markers', hoverinfo = 'text',
                        text = ~paste(interval)) %>%
                        layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y)
```

How do I get a [colorbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XXSx.png) in the legend where the colors are based on `Index` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
plot_ly(mydata, x = ~A, y = ~B, type = "scatter",
        mode = 'markers', hoverinfo = 'text', colors = colorRampPalette(c("red", "black"), space = "rgb")(20), color = ~Index, text = ~paste(interval), marker = list(size=14)) %>%
        layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y) %>%
        colorbar(title = "My Legend")
```